# PHP login form issue on server

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session

I have created a php login form, which works fine using xampp & phpmyadmin,

but when I upload it to my server, I can register a user but get the following error when trying to log in.

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /php/index.php:9) in /php/login.php on line 24

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /php/index.php:9) in /php/login.php on line 24

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /php/index.php:9) in /php/login.php on line 28
```

i have php included the login form on the index.php page

the login.php code is...

```
    <?php include("dbconnect.php"); ?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit1"])){

if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];



    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$user."' AND password='".$pass."'");
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows!=0)
    {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $dbusername=$row['username'];
    $dbpassword=$row['password'];
    }

    if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)
    {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;

    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: member.php");
    }
    } else {
    echo "Invalid username or password!";
    }

} else {
    echo "All fields are required!";
}
}
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that this is all the code in that page?
The errors means that your output something (like `echo`) prior to the `session_start()` line.

Comment: Add your code as text to your question not as a link

Comment: Yes, that is everything on that page, I do have this page included on index.php, I also have another 5 or 6 different includes on index.php (if that has anything to do with it)

Comment: Empty line at the beginning? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Answer (score 1):

use `ob_start()` - Turn on output buffering

This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.

Comment: `ob_start()` does not fit as solution in this case. And it just hides the problem never solves it. Since OP is also including more files in his code as well.

Comment: after session_start();

Comment: I have tried adding this, but the errors are still there

Comment: your session_start(); should be on the top of the page.. make sure this is on the top in you page

Answer (score 1):

session_start(); should be first line of your code file.

```
 <?php



    if(isset($_POST["submit1"])){
    session_start(); 
    include("dbconnect.php"); 

    if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
        $user=$_POST['user'];
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];



        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$user."' AND password='".$pass."'");
        $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($numrows!=0)
        {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
        $dbusername=$row['username'];
        $dbpassword=$row['password'];
        }

        if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)
        {

        $_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;

        /* Redirect browser */
        header("Location: member.php");
        }
        } else {
        echo "Invalid username or password!";
        }

    } else {
        echo "All fields are required!";
    }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this but it still does not work, i am getting the same errors, but this time, before i press login,

Comment: okay can you please paste login form code and dbconnect file code.  also make sure there should be no space before php start tag <?php

Comment: I have added all code to this url http://notepad.cc/wieveko89, there is the login.php, dbconnect.php & member.php

Comment: login.php remove space before <?php  tag if there
<?php
//login page
session_start();

Comment: all spaces have been removed, the error still occurs 
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /php/index.php:9) in /hp/login.php on line 2

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /php/index.php:9) in /php/login.php on line 2

Comment: @user2103072 just edited my code can you please try now

Comment: The error is still coming up, when the login button is pressed, the errors appear.